# I want to show the data in the roomDB in the recyclerview, but it is impossible to import the data

Tags: android, sqlite, roomdb

Adapter class

```
package com.example.breakingblock.roomdb

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.breakingblock.databinding.LocalRankingitemBinding

class UserAdapter(private var dataSet: MutableList<user>):RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(val binding : LocalRankingitemBinding) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LocalRankingitemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
    }
    fun setList(newList: MutableList<user>) {
        this.dataSet = newList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        Log.d("UserAdapter", "Data set: $newList")
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val binding = (holder as MyViewHolder).binding
        binding.nickname.text=dataSet[position].name
        binding.score.text=dataSet[position].score.toString()

    }
}
```

DAO interface

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface scoreDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(user: user): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    suspend fun selectAll(): MutableList<user>
}
```

a fraction of main activity

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var gameView: GameView
    private var bgmPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth // 파이어베이스 인증 객체
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient // 구글 로그인 클라이언트 객체
    private val REQ_SIGN_GOOGLE = 100
    private var backPressedTime: Long = 0
    private lateinit var db: ScoreDatabase
    private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        db = ScoreDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)




        // 파이어베이스 인증 객체 초기화
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        // 구글 로그인 옵션 설정
        val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        // 구글 로그인 클라이언트 초기화
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions)

        // 미디어 플레이어 초기화
        bgmPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.titlemusic)
        bgmPlayer?.isLooping = true



        // 구글 로그인 버튼 클릭시
        binding.btnGoogle.setOnClickListener {
            bgmPlayer?.pause()
            val intent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_SIGN_GOOGLE)
        }

        // 게임 스타트 버튼 클릭시
        binding.gamestart.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, GameViewActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        // 로컬 랭킹 버튼 클릭시
        binding.localrank.setOnClickListener {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                adapter = UserAdapter(mutableListOf())
                val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.local_ranking_view, null)
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    .setView(dialogView)
                    .create()

                val recyclerView = dialogView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.localrank_recycler_view)
                recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@MainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))

                val userList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { db!!.scoreDao().selectAll() }
                adapter.setList(userList) // 기존 adapter에 새로운 데이터 목록 설정

                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                dialog.show()
            }
        }
```

When I pressed the localrank button, I want to display the data in the roomDB in recylerview, but when I printed the log, there was nothing in the userlist, so what's the reason?
It was confirmed through data inspection that the data was inserted correctly.
I wonder how I can display the data in roomDB in a recycling review. And I wonder why no data is accepted even though I did select all